# Remove focus from the omnibox when redirecting from a WebExtension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a [Address Bar Suggestion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Omnibox) extension that I am working on.

Using the example code provided in that link, `browser.tabs.update({url});` will leave the address bar selected after loading the selected URL.

I would like the address bar to lose focus, the same as if the user had pressed enter. Is that possible?

Perusing the docs for [`tabs.update`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/update), I tried passing the `active` flag with no change. <s>Passing the `highlighted` flag resulted in</s>

```
Type error for parameter updateProperties (Property "highlighted" is unsupported by Firefox) for tabs.update.
```

Even though it's marked as supported. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

EDIT: `highlighted` is not marked as supported. Thanks @evilpie

Is removing focus from the address bar possible using these APIs?

Comment: Under Firefox  for "highlighted" I see "No" in the Browser compatibility table, did you look somewhere else? I think you might be able to do something like `tabs.executeScript({code: "window.focus()"})` ?

Comment: Huh, you're right, it is marked no. Not sure where I was looking. I tried `      browser.tabs.update({url: url, active: false}).then(() => { console.log("here"); browser.tabs.executeScript({code: "window.focus()"}) });
` and no joy. I see a "here" but no loss of focus. I'm going to shove this code up to GitHub.